Increase speed of two for loops in Python
I have a double for loop in a Python code. I want to increase the execution speed, but the matrix is built using data from the previous row and column. How can I achieve this?
import numpy as np

num_rows, num_cols = 100, 5

matrix = np.zeros((num_rows, num_cols))

matrix[0, :] = np.random.rand(num_cols)
matrix[:, 0] = np.random.rand(num_rows)

coeff1 = np.random.rand(num_rows)
coeff2 = np.random.rand(num_rows)
coeff3 = np.random.rand(num_rows)

result = np.zeros_like(matrix)

for j in range(1, num_cols):
    for n in range(1, num_rows):
        
        term1 = coeff1[n] * matrix[n-1, j-1]
        term2 = coeff2[n] * matrix[n, j-1]
        term3 = coeff3[n] * matrix[n-1, j]
        
        result[n, j] = term1 + term2 + term3


Make it Fully vectorized :
# Vectorized calculation for each j > 0
 # Prev row, prev col (term1)
term1 = coeff1[1:, None] * matrix[:-1, :-1] 
# Current row, prev col (term2)
term2 = coeff2[1:, None] * matrix[1:, :-1]  
# Prev row, current col (term3) 
term3 = coeff3[1:, None] * matrix[:-1, 1:]  

# Summing the terms to get the result matrix (vectorized)
result[1:, 1:] = term1 + term2 + term3


Use NumPy's vectorized operations like this:
for j in range(1, num_cols):
    term1 = coeff1[1:] * matrix[:-1, j-1]
    term2 = coeff2[1:] * matrix[1:, j-1]
    term3 = coeff3[1:] * matrix[:-1, j]

    result[1:, j] = term1 + term2 + term3

This is about 12 times faster on my system.

i tried this solution, but dont lead to the same results.

I can confirm that in the given code with the same np.random.seed the results are identical. Do you perform any other operations perhaps? Also, check the @Soudipta-Dutta's answer. That is probably much better.

The idea of making something faster, to be fair is quite synonymous to C/C++ . But you are in luck since you are currently using numpy.
I would go for Numba.
According to the docs.

NumPy-aware optimizing compiler for Python. It uses the LLVM compiler
project to generate machine code from Python syntax. Numba can compile
a large subset of numerically-focused Python, including many NumPy
functions. Additionally, Numba has support for automatic
parallelization of loops, generation of GPU-accelerated code, and
creation of ufuncs and C callbacks.

A code snippet to guide you.
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def numba_func(matrix, coeff1, coeff2, coeff3, result, num_rows, num_cols):
    for j in range(1, num_cols):
        for n in range(1, num_rows):
            term1 = coeff1[n] * matrix[n-1, j-1]
            term2 = coeff2[n] * matrix[n, j-1]
            term3 = coeff3[n] * matrix[n-1, j]
            result[n, j] = term1 + term2 + term3

num_rows, num_cols = 100, 5
matrix = np.zeros((num_rows, num_cols))
matrix[0, :] = np.random.rand(num_cols)
matrix[:, 0] = np.random.rand(num_rows)

coeff1 = np.random.rand(num_rows)
coeff2 = np.random.rand(num_rows)
coeff3 = np.random.rand(num_rows)

result = np.zeros_like(matrix)

# Call the function with JIT-compiled speed
numba_func(matrix, coeff1, coeff2, coeff3, result, num_rows, num_cols)

If you want super fast, you can try using the parallel computing to speed up the process.
You can also use the vectorized function from numba too
See docs -> vectorized
You can do something like this
from numba import vectorize, int32, int64, float32, float64
import numpy as np
@vectorize([your inputs])
def f(x, y):
    return x + y



You can use the numpy library for this
import numpy as np

# Example matrix dimensions
n = 1000

# Initialize matrices
matrix = np.zeros((n, n))

# Fill matrix using NumPy (vectorized operations)
for i in range(1, n):
    matrix[i, 0] = matrix[i - 1, 0] + 1
    for j in range(1, n):
        matrix[i, j] = matrix[i - 1, j] + matrix[i, j - 1] - matrix[i - 1, j - 1]



The OP is already using NymPy!

These are not vectorized operations.
